# How do I change color of an image element in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to change the color of the blue ring around the devil from royal blue to white.

I keep receiving a message that says `You can not use the Color Replacement tool because it does not work with alpha channels.`

1. What does that mean?
2. Can I change the color of the ring to white without using the Color Replacement tool?

[image]

Comment: An Alpha Channel is a channel holding transparency data. Look at the Channels Panel... are you working on an alpha channel or are you working on a layer mask (which is an alpha channel)?

Comment: First, THANK YOU FOR YOUR RESPONSE!
I'm sorry, I'm a real novice. How do I know?
When I click on the Channels folder it brings up 5 thumbnails; RGB, Red, Green, Blue, and a completely blank square labeled Quick Mask.

Comment: I did remove the white square background -- which turned into checkered boxes. But I did that -- and need to keep it that way -- so I can use the ring as an o or zero..... o in MORAVIA or zero in 2015

Comment: You are in the Layer Pabel but earching for the channels pannel which keeps RGB, Reg, Green, Blue and Alpha. I don't know why you need to use color replacement for this. Can't you just select the outer circle and then press `delete` or `backspace` to make the outer circle transparent  by removing the blue color from the devil layer. Or you could just select everythibg except the circle and then press on "create mask" to mask the circle away which also makes its transparent

Comment: You're in Quick Mask mode.. tap the Q key on the keyboard to exit out of it.

Comment: Or if you want it white instead of transparent you could just create a fill color and use a mask on that fill color. The color will be visible at the areas that are white on the mask and invisible where its black. Thus you should make the whole mask black except the part of the outer ring. After that the ring will have the color of the fill color (white). You can edit the mask by clicking on it and just draw on it with grayscale colors and the brush tool. Please note that the fill color with the masks needs to be above the fevil layer to be visible

Comment: okay...whoa...whoa....mind=blown.

so I hot the Q key and now I can select the ring (THANK YOU SO MUCH)

how do I change it white?

Comment: *hit the Q key.

Comment: I want sure if you want the circle to be white or transparet. I wrote an answer on how to do both. If you want to circle to be white create a color fill on top of the devil-layer and create a mask for that color fill. Make the whole mask black and only make the parts white where you want your white to be. You only want the white to be over the outer circle so it turns white. See more detail within my answer.

Comment: what's the Devil Layer?
how do I create a colour fll?
how do I make the whole mask black?
how do I make the parts white (where I want the white to be)?

Comment: Whoa. You seem to lack *very* much of the basics. I'm sorry but I recommend you to get on yourube and watch a tutorial on how to use photoshop. Thats a really easy way of learning photoshop fast. Just watch the tutorials and redo the same on your machine. You will see that you'll learn all the basics pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to turn the circle into white or make it transparent then you are not searching for the channels and color replacement might be the wrong tool.

I dont know how much experience with Photoshop you have, thats why I link articles here to give you the opportunity to learn about the basics before fiddling with it. Photoshop in its core really is a very simple program and it makes fun to learn and use it.

### Turning the circle transparent

Just [select](http://designshack.net/articles/software/8-ways-to-get-the-selection-you-want-in-photoshop/) everything except the outer circle and press on "create mask".

The [mask](http://designshack.net/articles/graphics/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-masking-in-photoshop/) will be generated with black spots for the circle and white spots for the devil. The circle will be made transparent because of the mask.

You can edit that that mask by clicking on it and then just drawing with a brush or similar on it. You will not see the black/white pattern when you just select the mask but you will be able to see your image which makes it really easy for you just to draw with black on everything you dont want to see and draw with white on everything you want to see.

Alternatively to the mask-method you could [select](http://designshack.net/articles/software/8-ways-to-get-the-selection-you-want-in-photoshop/) nothing except the circle you want to remove and then just press `Delete` or `Backspace` on your keyboard. The selected parts will will be removed and thus are no longer visible.
I recommend the approach with the mask, because it's non-destructive and thus you are later able to restore or alternste the original image as well as the [mask](http://designshack.net/articles/graphics/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-masking-in-photoshop/).

### Turnung the circle white

Create a fill color with the color white and create a [mask](http://designshack.net/articles/graphics/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-masking-in-photoshop/) for the fill color. Same principle here as in the transparent section: Black color on the mask hides the layer, white color makes it visible.
You want to select the outer cirlce you want to dye white and then you make everything on the color fill mask white while keeping the other parts black.
This will create a fully white circle which perfectly fits onto your previously blue curcle and thus hides it. Please note that the fill color with the masks needs to be above the devil layer to be visible.

You also could create a new [layer](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/layers-intro/) and just fill the parts you need white with white without using a [mask](http://designshack.net/articles/graphics/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-masking-in-photoshop/). This will have the same result but when using a mask it gets really easy to change to color of the overlay later.

I recommend you to do both of the things I just explained to you so you can learn them and see how they affect the image and what you might need to do to keep image quality.

Sorry that I'm not able of putting puctures in here. I'm currently online from my phone.

I hope I was able to help you.
Have a nice day

### You need more information?

- [Working with Layers](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/layers-intro/)
- [How to select objects](http://designshack.net/articles/software/8-ways-to-get-the-selection-you-want-in-photoshop/)
- [Beginner’s Guide to Masking](http://designshack.net/articles/graphics/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-masking-in-photoshop/)

Comment: I have "selected" the out circle.... can I change the colour that way? I don't know how to "select everything else"

I'm sorry I am so dumb! It's embarrassing!

Comment: *outer circle....

Comment: You can press `crtl` + `shift` + `I` to invert the selection

Comment: OMG! I DID IT! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! SCOTT & JONAS!!!

Comment: I provided 3 links where you can learn on how layers, selection and masks work. If you dont know much about the topic i recommend you to look at it tonlesrn in. I can also recommend watching tutorials on youtube where tjey show you which buttons to press. There are many many tutorials out there which you can easily follow to get understanding on how photoshop works

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer with the checkmark icon to let everyone see that your problem is solved

Comment: Thank you! I have what I need... just making an alternate white text so I can order Navy Tees for the Football Team - with white text!!! THANKS AGAIN!!!!

Comment: At the top left of my answer you see up- and downvote buttons. Below that theres a grayed out checkmark you can click on to accept my answer. Every stackexchange use gains points for writing useful answers.